# How does Request.IsAuthenticated work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

MSDN Code Sample Description: The following code example uses the IsAuthenticated property to determine whether the current request has been authenticated. If it has not been authenticated, the request is redirected to another page where users can enter their credentials into the Web application. This is a common technique used in the default page for an application.

This is great but no detail or anything...

What exactly is it checking for? How do I set it to true?

Go the extra mile: Where would I find more detailed documentation about this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Thanks to Google, I found a cached version of the post @keyboardP refers to in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2201325/177710). I'm posting that answer/post here as a reference for others since the original link is broken (2012-12-06).

**[Original question](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2Z_nRCatkYMJ:www.dotnet247.com/247reference/message.aspx?vote=bfbaf71d-8903-4a47-b0cf-18ff1db2693c&id=114539&threadid=305905%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&lr=lang_en%7Clang_de%7Clang_pl) that the answer below refers to:**

I have a forms based application that is giving me fits. I noticed that, in
a location where the IsAuthenticated property had been True, it was now
false and the was not working as expected. I am wondering if I have a
setting that is invalid??

Can anyone tell me what sets the IsAuthenticated property to True--what
constitues logging in.

**Answer by Daniel Kent:**

`Request.IsAuthenticated` is not just for forms authentciation - it is valid
no matter what type of authentication is being used (Windows, Passport,
Forms or our own custom scheme)

`HttpRequest.IsAuthenticated` will be true when the user making the request
has been authenticated. Essentially, this property provides the same
information as `Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

At the start of a request, `Context.User.Idenity` contains a `GenericIdentity`
with a null username. The `IsAuthenticated` property for this object will
return `false` so `Request.IsAuthenticated` will be `false`. When an
authentication module handles the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event and
successfuly authenticates the user it replaces the `GenericIdentity` in
`Context.User.Identity` with a new `IIdentity` object that will return `true` from
its `IsAuthenticated` property. `Request.IsAuthenticated` will then return `true`.

In the case of Forms authentication, the forms authentication module uses
the encrypted authentication ticket contained in the authentication cookie
to authenticate the user. Once it has done this, it replaces the
`GenericIdentity` in `Context.User.Identity` with a `FormsIdentity` object that
returns `True` from its `IsAuthenticated` property.

So, setting `IsAuthenticated` to `true` is actually different to logging in. As
Jeff says, logging in to forms authentication happens when the
authentication ticket is generated and sent to the client as a cookie.
(`RedirectFromLoginPage` or `SetAuthCookie`) What we are talking about with
`IsAuthenticated` is authentication that happens with each page request.
Logging in happens when a user enters their credentials and is issued a
ticket, authentication happens with each request.

Comment: here is a link to google's cached answer: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:t4JNfp8peQIJ:https://forums.asp.net/t/1416811.aspx%3FQuestion%2Babout%2Bmethods%2Bto%2Bdetect%2Bif%2Ba%2Buser%2Bis%2Blogged%2Bin

Answer (score 8):

There's a quite detailed post by Daniel Kent [here](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/22/114539.aspx). (Snippet)

> Request.IsAuthenticated is
>   not just for forms authentciation - it
>   is valid no matter what type of
>   authentication is being used (Windows,
>   Passport, Forms or our own custom
>   scheme)
>
> HttpRequest.IsAuthenticated will be
>   true when the user making the request
>   has been authenticated. Essentially,
>   this property provides the same
>   information as
>   Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.

Comment: The link is unfortunately broken. I found a cached version through Google and posted its contents in a different answer for better formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Decompiling HttpRequest IsAuthenticated, it looks like this

```
    public bool IsAuthenticated {
        get {
            return(_context.User != null
                    && _context.User.Identity != null
                    && _context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
        }
    }
```

line 1373
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/HttpRequest.cs