# checking the existence of the user in the data store for authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

how to check that the user is authenticated. Asp.net tells me that the user is authorized If set cookies, but I need to check whether a user with the name in my data store. Where can I add additional checks?

Comment: An *authorized* user should already be *authenticated* (although I suppose that one could technically be "authorized but anonymous" for public operations). If authorization occurs before authentication, then something is broken. Just having a session cookie does *not* imply authentication or authorization.

Comment: Anyway, ASP.NET authentication providers have already been discussed to death and the required keywords to search for such discussions are present in the question.

Comment: I use the following code if the user has entered the correct password, and logs : FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(account.UserName, false). When I received the cookies, I clear the database. And after refreshing the page User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Use: `Request.IsAuthenticated`

Check the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated.aspx).

Also, Below is a great explanation taken from question: [How does Request.IsAuthenticated work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201238/how-does-request-isauthenticated-work)

**Request.IsAuthenticated is not just for forms authentciation - it is valid no matter what type of authentication is being used (Windows, Passport, Forms or our own custom scheme)**

HttpRequest.IsAuthenticated will be true when the user making the request has been authenticated. Essentially, this property provides the same information as Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.

At the start of a request, `Context.User.Idenity` contains a GenericIdentity with a null username. The IsAuthenticated property for this object will return false so `Request.IsAuthenticated` will be false. When an authentication module handles the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event and successfuly authenticates the user it replaces the GenericIdentity in `Context.User.Identity` with a new IIdentity object that will return true from its `IsAuthenticated` property. `Request.IsAuthenticated` will then return true.

In the case of Forms authentication, the forms authentication module uses the encrypted authentication ticket contained in the authentication cookie to authenticate the user. Once it has done this, it replaces the GenericIdentity in `Context.User.Identity` with a `FormsIdentity` object that returns True from its IsAuthenticated property.