# FormsAuthentication MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I am trying to get simple Forms Authentication setup with an MVC4 website.

In App_start/FilterConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
   filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
   filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

In Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" name=".ASPFORMSAUTH" />
</authentication>
  <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

In Controllers/AccountController:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View("~/Views/MyAccountViews/Login.cshtml");
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    ActionResult retVal = View("~/Views/MyAccountViews/Login.cshtml", model); 

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            retVal = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        } 
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Now when I debug this in Visual Studio, which lands on the base URL (say localhost:1111/) it correctly redirects to the login page (localhost:1111/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f)

However, if I just modify the URL back to localhost:1111/ and hit enter, I am able to access the site.  In this scenario, httpcontext.current.user.identity.name is still my Windows NT login name.  I have made sure to call FormsAuthentication.Logout to clear the cookie.  If I login, and set "PersistCookie" to true, don't call FormsAuthentication.Logout, and just reboot my debug session, I am still initially re-directed to the Login page, but can just circumvent by modifying the URL.  So, same results with and without the cookie.  How do I make this work with strictly Forms Authentication? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that the web.config Setting <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />?

Comment: If you are not using the provided simpleMembership you should turn it off with: <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />

Answer (score 1):

You need to add filter to check that user is authenticated/Authorized or not.

**1. Add following attribute**

public class AuthorizeWithSessionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{

if (httpContext.Session == null || httpContext.Session["XYZSession"] == null)

    return false;

return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
}
```

}

**2. Set the session after SetAuthCookie()**

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);

Session["XYZSession"] = "Set name/parameter";

**3. Set attribute before controller**

[AuthorizeWithSessionAttribute]

public class XYZController : Controller

Comment: Thank you. The above answer is working but still have one issue. Why Request.IsAuthenticated is still using Windows authentication?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Request.IsAuthenticated is valid for Windows, Passport, Forms or our own custom scheme Authentication, Please read this link: [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201238/how-does-request-isauthenticated-work)