# I started a new empty project in MVC4, Why is it checking windows authentication by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, form-authentication

I added below code in my web config and

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Home/Login" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

and while debugging in layout

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

it is showing windows authentication and making it true., where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Check this isn't in your web config  <!--<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>-->, just remove it or comment it out.

Comment: I couldn't find any code you mentioned, but I added               <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Home/Login" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>  in other web config file.                                              Now I am getting this error   : "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

Comment: Post your web config please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746673/formsauthentication-mvc4