# Razor pages dereference of possible null reference on User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

[image]

I have this if statement in the cshtml of a page. For some reason or another it keeps giving me that the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is dereference of possible null reference and when the program starts it doesn't consider the statement.How can it be fixed?

[this is after implementing your solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlbnB.png)

Addition: the error occurs on post

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Share more information about your project and a minimal reproducible example so people can help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the error. I called onGet method inside the onPost method before returning the page
example:

```
public void onGet()
{
//code
}
public void onPost()
{

//code 

onGet();

return Page();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
@if (User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
{
}
```

Check [Nullable contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) and [Null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

Comment: Uploaded the output from the implementation.

Answer (score -1):

I also get `Dereference of possible null reference` when using `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, but it's not ignored, it works, have you verified this page?

Other than that, maybe you can use [Request.IsAuthenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13748301/18789859) instead.

Comment: How can you verify the page?