# How long asp.net Request.IsAuthenticated last for?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication, httprequest

Is there any way to find out this? The reason behind this: it looks like Request.IsAuthenticated is valid longer than the session in my application.

Comment: Possible duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212503/asp-net-membership-isapproved-false-but-still-allowing-login

Comment: Can you show the code as to how you logout the user ??

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear you have to configure your membership provider to auto logout user after session timeout event.
You said you are getting Request.IsAuthenticated after session timeout time also.

**Note :** 
You can capture session timeout time in Session_End event of global.ascx file. 
You can log out you user forcefully here.
There is one more way to configure user activity idle time in membership provider. and asp.net framework will automatically logout user after this idle time.