# Does "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" returns null if session times out?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I working on an Formsauthentication sign in functionality.

My session configuration is 1minute,

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="1"/>
```

My forms authentication settings,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">      
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="~/" loginUrl="~/user/signin" name="PMPLUSWeb" timeout="21680" slidingExpiration="true"  />
</authentication>
```

I set the forms authentication as,

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userID, user.RememberMe);
```

So when I access "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" I get the userID.

If the session times out (after 1minute), I thought "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" will also expire. But the value persist, I still get the UserID after 1minute. Where does this value stored?

Is the value read from the cookie and sent via the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the *login cookie* expires (I'd avoid using the term ["session"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) here), then `HttpContext.Current.User` will return null and `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated` will return false

For more information on how User / IsAuthenticated are set, take a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1212503/3603) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201238/how-does-request-isauthenticated-work) questions.