# Does Forms authentication remember authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms-authentication

*preview: In my web.config - I don't use forms authentication. I set forms cookie myself.*

However - Sometimes I see code like this :

```
/*1*/   protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
/*2*/    {
/*3*/     if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
/*4*/       {
/*5*/        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
/*6*/          {
/*7*/              //...
/*8*/              HttpContext.Current.User = ....
/*9*/              //...
/*10*/          }
/*11*/        }
/*12*/   }
```

Looking at  line `#5` —

How can it ever be authenticated if line#8 is about to set authentication ?

I mean - line #8 is the one who set authentication for that *specific*  request and when the request is finished , there is no *"memory"* for future requests. ( cookie expiration is merely  - for how long to keep the persistent cookie).

**Question**

- In what scenarios would line `#5` return `true` ?
- In what scenarios would line `#3` would be `null` ?

*nb  , this question assumes that `begin_request` event is not setting anything  , and the only stage where authentication is set is on `Application_AuthenticateRequest`.* — I don't use membership engine.

---

placeholder :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289844(v=vs.71).aspx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line #3 can become null if the login cookie expires. 
Line #5 is true if the user is logged in.

It can seem like these two methods go hand-in-hand and in fact they do. It can be easier to check for `HttpRequest.IsAuthenticated`. For more information see here:

[asp.net membership IsApproved false but still allowing login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212503/asp-net-membership-isapproved-false-but-still-allowing-login)

And here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated%28loband%29.aspx

I do not have an answer to your main question though. Sorry.

In addition to my comment below you may find this link helps explain the abilities of adding roles to existing principles. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5k850zwb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: As you said , This is not an answer. line #8 is **about to set** authentication.  so it seems that line `#3` at stage `N` remembers the authentication from stage `N-1` ( ps I dont use membership)

Comment: I have been through the link you have provided and I think you have missed what the routine is doing. Line #8 is not setting authentication, after all it is reapplying the existing identity to the new princple it is generating. The link you proivded even explains it. The new principle is a copy of the old principle but the new one contains the roles associated with the user account. This is because you cannot add roles to the roles object of an existing principle object.

Comment: Craig , the act of setting Iprincipal object into `context.User` _IS_ what cause IsAuthenticate to get true/false. so it does set authentication. However I think I know what's my problem. I don't use forms authentication at the whole site. I set it regular and each request - I set Context.User with value. BUT(!) with forms authentication , it does it automatically. hence the _if_ condition.

Comment: Re-Reading your comment- you're right.it is merly to  add roles  - But (another question). Roles are NOT kept in the cookie. so where does it gets them from ?

Comment: **PS I think I know what happens. (please ack)** they store the Roles in the cookei as a Userdata property. (which is a bad thing becuase he cookie size is increased due to more data). what I(!) have done is to keep the roles information in the cache in dictionary. so I only need from the cookie - the Identification of the user , then onAuthenticate - I attach to  Context.User - the data from the cache.

Comment: Yes this sounds correct. By storing the information in a dictionary and then pulling that based on the user cookie you get their role data that way. Provided that you are attaching the role data to the Context.User object everything should work correctly. You may have a performance hit depending on where you store the dictionary but ultimately it should be negligable.

Comment: PS - At what stage Forms authentication put the value in Context.User ?

Comment: I honestly do not know.